# Read string then do the action

Tags: c

I need it to read the string and if it matches to the string of characters I put then it prints this message, otherwise prints the other message.

Here is what I was trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   char name[10];
 
   printf("Put your name in: \n");
   scanf("%s", name);
 
  if ((name='lucas' || (name=Lucas));
    printf("do this");
  } else{
     printf("do that");
  }
  
}
```

Comment: 1. Get it to compile 1st. 2 Look up `strcmp`

Comment: main.c:14:13: warning: multi-character character constant
      [-Wmultichar]
  if (name= 'lucas');
            ^
main.c:14:13: warning: character constant too long for its type
main.c:14:11: error: array type 'char [10]' is not assignable
  if (name= 'lucas');
      ~~~~^
main.c:16:5: error: expected identifier or '('
  } else{
    ^
main.c:21:1: error: extraneous closing brace ('}')
}

it gives me those messages
and since I'm not comparing 2 different string the strcmp didn't work either

Answer (score 2):

### Compare strings

You can compare strings using [`strcmp`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) from [`<string.h>`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/string_h.htm). The strings are equal when the return value is `0`, so this should be the condition in the if-statement:

```
if (strcmp(name, "lucas") == 0 || strcmp(name, "Lucas") == 0)
```

### Prevent buffer overflow

And just a note, It's a good idea to prevent a buffer overflow when scanning for user input using [`scanf`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) from [`stdio`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/stdio_h.htm).

```
char name[10];
/* take '\0' into account */
scanf("%9s", name);
```

### Entire code

There are some other problems with your code as well (e.g. `;` after `if` instead of `{`) so I rewrote the entire code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[10];
    printf("Your name: ");
    /* take '\0' into account */
    scanf("%9s", name);
    if (strcmp(name, "lucas") == 0 ||
        strcmp(name, "Lucas") == 0) {
        printf("Your name is Lucas.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Your name is not Lucas.\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If two strings are equal, `strcmp` returns `0`. In your example, it will to go the `else` part if the it is "Lucas" or "lucas".

Comment: @phoxis You are right, forgot that.

Comment: The `!` will do the job, but it can be a bit un-intuitive for someone who didn't use `strcmp` before as one can read it as "name does not match "lucas" ". I always do `strcmp (str, "foo") == 0` . This makes things clear. A personal choice though.

Comment: @phoxis I have now updated the answer.

Comment: I did  if (strcmp(name, 'lucas')) == 0 and  if (strcmp(name, "lucas")) == 0 and none of them worked.

Comment: @YgorSilva You have a semicolon `;` after the if-statement-condition instead of `{`. I have updated my answer and added the entire code.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `'lucas'` and `Lucas` do what you meant.

Additionally, even if they do, you can't compare this way, because the `=` operator is an assignment in C, not a comparison.

Finally, even if you used the correct comparison operator `==`, it will not test whether the strings have the same content, but just if they are *the same* string (i.e. they start at the same point in memory). See the comment by Ed Heal.

Comment: Got it. so what sould I use to do the work? strcmp doesn't seem to work the way I wanted to, I mean, I'm pretty sure the it is not working because I'm not using it right, since I never used the strcmp.

Comment: @YgorSilva [`strcmp`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) _does_ work. The problem is the `;` after `if` instead of `{`.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang There's more problems than just a semicolon. As Ed Heal pointed out in the very first comment, that code does not even compile! So either the question is just a bad joke, or the code is carelessly re-typed instead of copy+pasted. As a result we talk about _something else_ than YgorSilva, and the whole process doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @CiaPan The semicolon can be the reason for the program not being able to compile. In my answer I have provided working code.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang Yup, the misplaced semicolon causes a syntax error at a dangling `else`. But there are more uncompilable things there before the semicolon, see my answer again as well as the Ygor's own comment under the question....

Comment: @CiaPan Yeah the other mistake is the fact that he compares strings the wrong way.